# How to write queries to calculate today's due amount?

Tags: mysql

I have scheduled payments, so I have these tables:

```
customer
+id

paymentSchedule
+id
+customer_id
+amount  //total price 
+dueDate //date to be paid

payments
+id
+date
+customer_id
+paymentSchedule_id
+amount  //amount paid, it can be a partial payment
```

How do I write a query to get Today's due amount by customer.
I mean I need to join the tables (thats my main problem) and then substract the 
sum of the payments.mount minus the sum of the scheduledPaymens.amount
but.. how?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is how I understood the problem. I simplified the tables because they where just complicating things, and adding dates is just straight forward.

**PaymentSchedule**

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+
| id | customer_id | original_amount |
+----+-------------+-----------------+
|  1 | Tom         |             100 |
|  2 | Tom         |             200 |
|  3 | Tom         |             300 |
|  4 | Moe         |             400 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+
```

**Payments**

```
+----+--------------------+-------------+
| id | paymentSchedule_id | paid_amount |
+----+--------------------+-------------+
|  1 |                  1 |          70 |
|  2 |                  2 |         150 |
|  3 |                  2 |          50 |
|  4 |                  4 |         300 |
|  5 |                  4 |          25 |
+----+--------------------+-------------+
```

**Result of query**

```
+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+
| CUSTOMER_ID | PAYMENTSCHEDULEID | ORIGINAL_AMOUNT | TOTALPAID | PENDINGPAYMENT |
+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+
| Tom         |                 1 |             100 |        70 |             30 |
| Tom         |                 2 |             200 |       200 |              0 |
| Tom         |                 3 |             300 |         0 |            300 |
| Moe         |                 4 |             400 |       325 |             75 |
+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+
```

**Query with double select**

```
select *, s.original_amount - s.TotalPaid as PendingPayment from (
  select
    ps.customer_id, ps.id as PaymentScheduleId, ps.original_amount,
    coalesce(sum(p.paid_amount), 0) as TotalPaid
  from paymentSchedule ps
  left join payments p on p.paymentSchedule_id = ps.id
  group by ps.customer_id, PaymentScheduleId, ps.original_amount
) as S
```

**Query with single select**

```
select
  ps.customer_id, ps.id as PaymentScheduleId, ps.original_amount,
  coalesce(sum(p.paid_amount), 0) as TotalPaid,
  ps.original_amount - coalesce(sum(p.paid_amount), 0) as PendingPayment
from paymentSchedule ps
left join payments p on p.paymentSchedule_id = ps.id
group by ps.customer_id, PaymentScheduleId, ps.original_amount
```

The result of both queries is the same. I just wonder which one runs faster. You can try both and tell us :)

Let me know if this this is the result you expected

Comment: I understand your second version better, and helped me understand a lot, but I have problems getting the totals, I would like to modify it in order to give as a condition the Customer ID and return only the amount due (date<=now), i mean to get only a value as return.

Comment: Sorry, my english is not very good. What is amount due? If you can explain it using the column names of the `Result of query` section that would help a lot.

Comment: Sorry, my english is bad too! I meant the PendingPayment, but I already woorked that out by using your query, as a subselect, Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not 100%, but should be pretty solid to help you tweak:

```
SELECT customer_id, (due.amount - paid.amount) as amountDue
FROM
    (SELECT customer_id, SUM(amount) as amount 
     FROM paymentSchedule 
     WHERE dateDate <= getDate()
     and customer_id = @custid) as due
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT customer_id, SUM(amount) as amount
     FROM payments
     WHERE customer_id = @custid) as paid ON paid.customer_id = due.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be a good starting point for you to tweak.

```
    SELECT c.*
      FROM customer c
INNER JOIN paymentSchedule ps
        ON c.id = ps.customer_id
 LEFT JOIN payments p
        ON ps.id = p.paymentSchedule_id
     WHERE ps.dueDate = 'This depends on how you store dueDate'
       AND ps.amount - p.amount > 0
```

Comment: This works, but there is a problem. If there are no payments already in the payments table with the corresponding id, then those records are not included.